# Integrating MsBuild with Git

Tags: git, msbuild

Im looking for way to integrate MsBuild scripts with Git source control. The first thing I would like to make is to create Task that creates Git Tag at sources.

MsBuild Comunity Tasks looks like doesn't have any support for Git.
Any ideas how to connect these two is much appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason not to confine this behaviour to your CI environment?

Comment: @Ritch Melton, not all of my projects are in CI at now. Im planning to take it there in the future, but not at this moment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending what you are doing and if you want to keep it simple, just use the `Exec` task to call the appropriate git command, like `git tag`

You can otherwise look at extending MSBuild and write tasks that make use of these `git commands` or you can make use of [GitSharp](https://github.com/henon/GitSharp)

Comment: Who is downvoting my answers without any comment??

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here a few years after the original question, you can now find git task support in MSBuild.Community.Tasks

https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/tree/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/Git

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use TeamCity to have a couple of different branches to build off of. Let one of them be a release candidate branch and have TeamCity auto-tag it for you. This should allow you to not bother with MSBuild tinkering.

Hope this helps.